# captcha refreshing with refresh button

Tags: php, javascript, captcha

I am developing a website with php, i'm also using javascript in it.

I have to refresh captcha in my website with a refresh button when a captcha is unreadable to a user.

how can i do this.
please share any idea or codes to me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you hand-rolling this out yourself? Did you try Recaptcha? http://recaptcha.net/whyrecaptcha.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ReCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/) .

Otherwise it depends on the way you have implemented it .. Ajax seems like the way to go ..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [ReCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/) is the perfect, and safe solution to go for, just register there and implement that on your site, it should not be that difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have an implementation of Captcha on your website. An approach suitable for your needs is an Ajax request. [**Ajax (XMLHTTPRequest) Tutorial**](http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/ajax_page.html)

If you do not want to hard-code everything and have the work already done for you, look at [**reCAPTCHA**](http://recaptcha.net/) or any other Captcha providing company. Although, not entirely sure if they offer a non-refreshing captcha page.

I have no experience in using it, besides when editing posts too many times, StackOverflow will redirect me to the *"Human Verification"* page.

Comment: You don't want to refresh the page? You might need to perform an AJAX request for that.